# Typeahead JSON request Access-control-allow-origin

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use Typeahead to read Belgian postal codes. I'm using a website which provides json files upon typing but I get an access-control-allow-origin error.  I'm viewing my web application through `localhost`. What am I doing wrong here? I'm using typeahead 0.11.1

This is the script throwing the error:

```
     <script>
        var postalCodes = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Postcode'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: 'http://www.opzoeken-postcode.be/%QUERY.json',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'postal-codes',
            display: 'Postcode',
            source: postalCodes
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: The error message is an "access-control-allow-origin" error.